# How to build Docker Pi image on x86

Tags: docker

I'm doing Java development on Mac and I am trying to build an ARM docker container from my mac that will run on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian. I am able to find docker containers that will run on a Pi, but I cannot figure out how to build one myself.

I am pretty new to Docker, so explaining like I'm five would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As a Newcomer to Docker, I would recommend you to read at least the `best practice` of Docker. 
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#general-guidelines-and-recommendations

**To Answer your Question** "How to to build a container yourself" start with a simple `Hello World` to understand the usage plus Intention of Docker.
After that, just try To build your own Docker, you will need a 
`Dockerfile`, which is the building instructions for a Docker Container.

**How to write such a Dockerfile**: This should be your Task to check the `best Pratice above`

For additional Examples, here is a `Dockerfile` of mine (Ive used Golang instead of Java). After you have read the documentation I suspect you will understand it, if not just ask specific.

```
FROM golang:1.10.3 as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/git....../yourName/dht22
COPY . .
RUN go tool dist list | grep arm \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi \
    && go get ./... \
    && CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm 
       GOARM=6 go build -a -o app dht22.go

FROM arm32v6/alpine:latest
WORKDIR /go/src/git...../yourName/dht22
COPY --from=builder /go/src/git..../yourName/dht22 /app
CMD ['/app']
```